# javaFX Transform node across boundaries of parent

Tags: layout, javafx

Not sure how to express the question. Please forgive me if not clear.

As shown in the image below, I would like to drag a node (circle) across a parent (pane) and once the node cross the boundary of the parent, the part that is outside would appear on the opposite end.

How do I go about making this? Am I looking at reflection? Or some way of making inverse transforms?is there something around the corner in Javafx current API that permits this ? 
[image: example]

Comment: I think the solution has something to do with detecting when the dragging leaves the boundaries of the parent, but without some sample code it is difficult to propose a solution.

Comment: I will do an experiment code and update my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the node is always a `Circle`, which is a [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html), it is possible to make use of [intersect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#intersect-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-) and [subtract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#subtract-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-) from `Shape`.

1. Get intersection `Shape` of `Circle` and your `Pane` (`Pane` can be represented as a `Rectangle` with corresponding width and height). You use this as the one that appears on "this" end.
2. Subtract the obtained `Shape` from `Circle` to get another `Shape` which is the one that appears on the "opposite" end.

Shapes are also nodes, so you can draw them straight away, as soon as you computed them.